# How should I go about memory management in a java game?

Tags: java, javafx, memory-management

I embarked on a pretty ambitious project: I decided I was going to make a game with JavaFX. I've been working on it off and on for months, and all has gone smoothly, but I am running into an issue:

I'm making a bullet hell game, and so there is lots and lots of bullet objects, and after around 10 seconds of continuous firing, my framerate will drop from 60 to 20 in about 2 seconds. I assume this is a memory management issue. It's a problem I've never had to face, and so I don't really know much about it.

I do know that once an object has no more references to it, it will be deleted by the garbage collector. I tried to keep this in mind when designing it, trying to reduce my references to objects. When the bullets go off the screen and know they won't be used again, I try to remove the references to those objects. The way I designed it, there should only be a single reference to the object that I need to clear, but it obviously isn't working.

How can I see where these objects are being referenced? I realized thats probably not even possible, but I just don't really know what I can do to clear them from the memory.

After giving it some thought, its my suspicion that variables within an object could be referencing that object. Is that the way java works? Do I need to clear each variable within each object in order for the garbage collector to remove it?

(it should be noted that this is my first time making a java game using a timed loop (AnimationTimer) outside of my highschool game design class, in which we used Greenfoot which handled all the behind the scenes. I didn't really do much research on the best way to setup everything for a game, but at this point its too late to go back and restructure it.)

Comment: When the bullets don't need to be displayed anymore or are off screen, set them to null or destroy/release the resources consumed by a bullet

Comment: Do you know this is a memory issue or could it be algorithmic/compute based?  Quick answers to questions: yes, objects that still have references open won't be garbage collected.

Comment: Also, the type of tool you're looking for is called a profiler.  You can hook it up to your program and see memory usage with breakdowns for what's being used.

Comment: I recommend recreating a game using a tutorial. This will allow you to become familiar with different programming concepts before you start to develop your own versions of games. [Very good tutorial](https://carlfx.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/javafx-2-gametutorial-part-1/).  I would also suggest going through [JameD's games of GitHub and GitHub's Gist](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8149902). [This](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835) is also great.

Comment: For the really advanced stuff, follow [this blog](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com/) and [this GitHub](https://github.com/jperedadnr).

Comment: Even if there are no more strong references to an object this does not mean the GC collects it immediately. It just means it may collect it at some time in the future. One possibility to migrate this would be reusing the bullet objects. However there could be a lot of other things that could influence performance. If those bullet object are part of a layout that requires the layout being recalculated this could eat up a lot of performance...